# how to add arcgis button in a windows form

Tags: arcgis

I am new in ArcGis. I came across a requirement that I need a command on the ArcGis Toolbar. On click the command, a Windows Form will open and there one region selector button is there. upon clicking on the button, the current Form UI must be minimized and the user will be allowed to draw a polygon. Can you please help on how to do that.  Here is the code. I took normal windows button and wrote the below code in the click event.

```
        _application = ((IApplication)_hookHelper.Hook);
        IMxDocument pMxDoc = (IMxDocument)_application.Document;
        IMap pMap = (IMap)pMxDoc.FocusMap;

        IActiveView pActiveView = (IActiveView)pMap;

        if (pActiveView == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        //// Changing the state of the Window.
        if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal || this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized)
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
            // this.Hide();
        }

        ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.IScreenDisplay screenDisplay = pActiveView.ScreenDisplay;
        // Constant
        screenDisplay.StartDrawing(screenDisplay.hDC, (System.Int16)ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.esriScreenCache.esriNoScreenCache); // Explicit Cast

        ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.IRgbColor rgbColor = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.RgbColorClass();
        rgbColor.Blue = 111;

        ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.IColor color = rgbColor; // Implicit Cast
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.ISimpleFillSymbol simpleFillSymbol = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.SimpleFillSymbolClass();
        simpleFillSymbol.Color = color;

        ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.ISymbol symbol = simpleFillSymbol as ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.ISymbol; // Dynamic Cast
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.IRubberBand rubberBand = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.RubberRectangularPolygonClass();
        // ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.IRubberBand rubberBand = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.RubberPolygonClass();
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IGeometry geometry = rubberBand.TrackNew(screenDisplay, symbol);
        screenDisplay.SetSymbol(symbol);
        screenDisplay.DrawPolygon(geometry);
        screenDisplay.FinishDrawing();
```

I am also not getting any mouse event and the UI is not minimized while starting drawing the polygon. Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 0):

Have we check the white paper for ArcGIS runtime SDK for .Net?

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/runtime-wpf/concepts/index.html#/Essential_vocabulary/01700000004z000000/